# Make Java Program Loop until x is entered?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, break

I want to make my program loop until the user types in `x` instead of a number. I tried using a while statement but I do not know how to use it with multiple variables. Here is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int denominatorOne = 1, numeratorOne = 1;
    System.out.println("Welcome, type an \"x\" at any point to exit the program");
    while (numeratorOne !=x)
    {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);


        //Prompt the user for fraction one
        System.out.print("Enter the first numerator (top number): ");
        numeratorOne = in.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the first denominator (bottom number): ");
        denominatorOne = in.nextInt();
    }
}
```

The exact phrasing from my assignment is `The program should run in loop and allow the user to exit with some special character input (e.g. x or X to exit)`

Comment: `x` isn't a number...

Comment: 'x' is not an integer, thus it cannot be a sentinel value here unless you read the input as a string. You could say `if( input.equals('x') ) break;` and otherwise perform `Integer.parseInt(input);`.

Comment: are you aware about WrapperClass? Try to parse the input, if it is not an integer, then its sure that user typed something else, so it will throw exception, just catch and exit your loop...this is just a tip to help you start with..

Answer (score 4):

First off, 'x' isn't a number and won't be accepted by nextInt or a comparison to 'x', you should trying checking to see if it has next int (`in.hasNextInt()`) and process depending. Besides the point, you can easily test two variables in a while loop. Assuming you set up the variables right to be chars:

```
do {
    // scan code.
} while(!(numChar1.equals('x') && numChar2.equals('x')))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just call the method over again in this case main();.

What I suggest however is to create a new method, in the method just checking the users input returning the input as a string. Then you can check the string in your main method, and if that's not the string you wanted then recall the method. Here's an example, please note I didn't use an IDE for this.

```
public String getMessage(){
Scanner input = System.in();
return input;
}

public void checkMessage(String wantedString){
if(!getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase(wantedString)){
System.out.println("Please retry");
checkMessage();
}
}

public static void main(String[] args){
checkMessage();
}
```

Comment: `if(!getMessage.equalsIgnoreCase(wantedString)){` getMessage is a method, and not a variable!

Comment: Like I said, I didn't use an IDE for this, so I forgot the parenthesis, my apologies for that.

Answer (score 1):

what you need to do is have a bool value that holds the loop and when have a if statement check for the keydown event in the loop

bool looping = true

while ( looping == true)
{

if (x button was pressed == true)

{looping = false
}

}

Answer (score 1):

try changing it to

```
while(!numeratorOne.equals("x")){...}
```